how to expose functions from flutter through web view to the websites being opened through flutter web view, so they can be called from javascript
I need to expose some functionality that can be called from web app that is called in flutter_webview package so this website can access device native resources through app. but not directly accessing them but through my functions so it can be monitored and controlled. The idea is to create a channel or to take advantage of the native app functionality although it is a web view and make the most of it.
I tried using javascript channels functionality to setup communication between the web view and flutter app. but just simply using the messages is not good enough to achieve the functionality I am trying to achieve. I need to be able to take full advantage of the app functionalities and other services in the app and let some web app use some functionality of the app without exposing app internal code.
I need to expose some function and when called from javascript or from outside the app runs its own logic, to complete the operation. it can be an api call or something else.

By mentioning JS channels usage you mean you tried .runJavaScript('some function') and it was not enough for your application?

Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

You can actually try to use WebViewController to open app in WebView. The controller have function called runJavaScript. This command will be done in console of web application. So you can try to create controller like this
WebViewController controller = WebViewController()
      ..setJavaScriptMode(JavaScriptMode.unrestricted)

and then you can just call functions like this to pass data to your web app
controller.runJavaScript('applications.setMobileData(${your application data})')

or something like this.
If you want to use app functions in your web app you can combine JS functions and navigation. You can set navigation delegate for your controller and run js functions when user try to change page, for example:
controller..setNavigationDelegate(
    NavigationDelegate(
      onWebResourceError: (WebResourceError error) {},
      onNavigationRequest: (NavigationRequest request) {
        if (request.url == 'some_url') {
          controller.runJavaScript('applications.setMobileData(${your application data})')
        }
        
        return NavigationDecision.prevent;
      },
    ),
  );

